# Why does Intellij copy and overwrite my filtered web.xml when using tomcat run configuration?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, web.xml

I'm working with a Maven Webproject and Intellij IDEA (2018.2). The **web.xml** is being filtered by Maven (it contains two placeholders which are being filled through Maven Resource filtering, e.g.

`<session-timeout>${application.session.timeout}</session-timeout>`

).

My problem now is: I got two run-configurations, one which **builds the project via maven** and the other which **deploys the application as an exploded artefact** to my local Tomcat (v8.5). If I build it, the web.xml gets processed correctly and the placeholders are being switched with the values, which I can check in the exploded artefact folder under **/target**. But when I run the deploy-run-config, the web.xml is being **overwritten by the one in my src/main/resources** folder. This is standard behaviour I think, but what can I do now in my situation? The web.xml needs to be processed by maven, otherwise it doesn't work, but the deploy-config always overwrites it... Is it so uncommon to use filtering for the web.xml?

Comment: What are the Run/Debug Configuration types are those? What actions do you have in 'Before launch' section for both configurations?

Comment: The Maven-Run-Config is just a basic Maven Run Config which calls "clean install", it has nothing in the "Before launch"-area.

The Tomcat-Run-Config has just the exploded artefact, I didn't change any of the other settings except "On Update action" and "On frame deactivation". In the "Before launch"-area it has "Build" and "Build 'web:war exploded' artefact", which is the default setting.

Comment: `In the "Before launch"-area it has "Build" and "Build 'web:war exploded' artefact", which is the default setting.` Try to remove "Build" step in Before launch section and build only by Maven configuration. If issue remains please report it with a minimal sample project at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA